# SQL Communications link failure when accessing SQL database on the same machine

Tags: mysql, sql, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am running a Minecraft server which is querying a SQL database on the same VPS as the game server for various bits of data (ranks, warps and such). Today have encountered something which has stumped me and I am turning to you hoping for an answer.

My VPS is running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS, the Minecraft server is being ran from within a screen instance and no changes to the server, operating system or mySQL that I am aware of have been made that could have caused an issue and given I am the only one with SSH access to the server theres no way an update could have been made unless it was silently updated in the background without my knowledge. The problem just randomly happened out of nowhere.

The specific error I am getting (output from MC server console)

```
2021-05-19 12:44:51 [INFO] [STDOUT] [SERVERMANAGER EXCEPTION | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException] Communications link failure
2021-05-19 12:44:51 [INFO] [STDOUT] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Granted I have little experience with SQL (I inherited this SQL setup from someone else who I am unable to contact for assistance to fix this) but the last message of this error lead me to believe that everything with the Minecraft server itself was fine and the SQL database simply was not acknowledging the packets the Minecraft server was sending.

However despite...

1. Restarting the mySQL service with `sudo service mysql restart`
2. Verifying that the servermanager database I am using is still present with `SHOW DATABASES;`
3. Verifying that the three tables servermanager has are still present with `SHOW TABLES;`
4. Restarting the VPS

I cannot for the life of me seem to get this issue to fix itself!

Anyone able to offer any insight?

Comment: Your question is actually conflicting on  what RDBMS you are using. You state, at the start *"which is querying a SQL server"* but later on your refer to MySQL, and even restart a MySQL service, not a SQL Server service.

Comment: My bad, I used incorrect terminology here. I will edit my question to account for this. I am very inexperienced with SQL, apologies!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)